# Calculating unique masons by grouping consequent last months in a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataset with columns:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Mason_Id = sample(c("Mason1", "Mason2","Mason3","Mason4","Mason5","Mason6"), 12, T),
                 Registration_Date = c("01-08-2020", "01-08-2020","05-08-2020","07-08-2020",
                          "02-09-2020", "02-09-2020","02-09-2020",
                          "03-09-2020","04-09-2020","01-10-2020","02-10-2020",
                          "06-10-2020"),
                 Token_Count = runif(12, 10, 100), stringsAsFactors = F)

#calculate last day of every month
library(lubridate)
df$month_end_date=paste(format(df$Registration_Date, format="%m-%Y"),"-", days_in_month(df$Registration_Date), sep="")
```

I need to find the unique number of masons in the last 3 months starting October and moving backwards, in the following format:

```
Registration_Date | Unique_Masons
31-10-2020   |   5(unique masons in Oct,Sep, Aug) 
30-09-2020   |   x1(unique masons in Sep, Aug, July)
31-08-2020   |   x2(unique masons in Aug, July, June)
... and so on.
```

I have tried summarizing the data by quarter and monthly basis but it has not worked for me.
Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you just find last three months and find unique masons per month?

Comment: Actually, the dataset is just a sample of the original. Here data is until August but actually the months goes back to April 2015. The months need to be grouped by in a reverse order i.e. oct,sep,aug; sep,aug,july; aug,july,june; july,june,may.. and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
clean_df <- transform(
  df,
  Month_Vec = as.Date(gsub("^\\d{2}", "01", Registration_Date), "%d-%m-%Y"),
  Registration_Date = as.Date(Registration_Date, "%d-%m-%Y")
)

drng <- range(clean_df$Month_Vec)+31

eom_df <- merge(clean_df, 
            data.frame(eom = seq(drng[1], drng[2], by = "1 month")-1, 
            Month_Vec = sort(unique(clean_df$Month_Vec))), by = "Month_Vec", all.x = TRUE)

lapply(unique(eom_df$Month_Vec), 
  function(x){
    lower_lim <- seq(x, length = 2, by = "-3 months")[2]
    sbst <- subset(eom_df, Month_Vec >= lower_lim & Month_Vec <= x)
    data.frame(
      Registration_Date = max(sbst$eom),
      Unique_Masons = paste0(length(unique(sbst$Mason_Id)), "(Unique Masons in ",
        paste0(unique(month.abb[as.integer(substr(sbst$Month_Vec, 6, 7))]), 
        collapse = ", "), ")"
      )
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract 3 months from  `Registration_Date` and find out how many unique `Mason_Id` are present between the two dates.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Registration_Date = dmy(Registration_Date),
         month_end_date = ceiling_date(Registration_Date, 'month') - 1, 
         three_month = month_end_date %m-% months(3) + 1,
         Unique_Masons = purrr::map2(three_month, month_end_date,
                 ~n_distinct(Mason_Id[between(Registration_Date, .x, .y)]))) %>%
  distinct(month_end_date, Unique_Masons) %>%
  arrange(desc(month_end_date))

#  month_end_date Unique_Masons
#1     2020-10-31             6
#2     2020-09-30             5
#3     2020-08-31             3
```